# Is it possible to have azure automatically compile my C# code with continuous deployments?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a website (the api is C#) that automatically deploys to azure from the master branch of my git repository. Whenever a new deployment is complete, I hit the api and wait while relevant files are compiled. The wait is only for the first call to a particular controller.

I realize that I could make a script to hit the api and cause it to compile everything (so that real users don't have to wait), but then I would have to maintain a script when new features are added.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "compile"??? When you publish an Azure website, you push the "bin" folder, so the code is already compiled into dlls...

Comment: I didn't set up the project initially, but I know that the bin folder is in the .gitignore.

Comment: How exactly are you deploying the website?

Comment: Specifically, are you pushing your code into a git repository of the Azure website, or a different repository that you've linked the website to?  For reference, I push to an Azure Website Git Repo, and it most definitely compiles the code before deployment.

Comment: I'm pushing to a private github repository.